# Nested accordion hide and show Table Rows [where grandparent , parent , child are table rows]

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 rows that follow the grandparent, parent, child hierarchy. I have managed to create this using data-toggle and data-target.

So I can open these in a hierarchical order.
The issue is that I am not able to close both parent and child by clicking on the grandparent.

How can I solve that?

[image: Table Structure Image]

I chose table rows because I have to align the child element with respect to the table header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try including the full code. right now, your question is just badly written.

Comment: you can solve that with some javascript code